# Screen gose black while getting data from webservice in android

Tags: android, json, web-services

I am open new window that is showing data from web service. Whenever I click on button to jump on next window it goes black. Give me some suggestion.

Comment: it would help if you could share some code

Comment: A code sample would help, but generally, be certain you're not doing net traffic (or any other slow thing) on the UI thread.  Put it in an `AsyncTask`, or better yet, a `Runnable`.

Answer (score 1):

Code example would help.

Most likely you are doing the network operation on the main thread (The UI thread). That is a bad practice. Though it is the easiest way, it worsens responsivity of your application, if the network connection is poor it is possible that the application wont respond in a reasonable amount of time. Look at android documentation for [optional solution](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask)